# Reading and writing user profile properties using SSOM

Tags: user-profile, user-profile-property, ssom

The code works. There is no error.

Please let me know if this is the best practice to read/write to the user profile property in SharePoint 2013.

Read:

```
string currentUser = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName;
                SPSite spSite = SPContext.Current.Site;

                try
                {
                    // Set the context of the site to the SPSite site
                    SPServiceContext context = SPServiceContext.GetContext(spSite);
                    //Create and instance of the UserProfileManager
                    UserProfileManager profileManager = new UserProfileManager(context);
                    UserProfile userProfile = profileManager.GetUserProfile(currentUser);
                    string customValue=userProfile["customPropertyName"].Value.ToString();
                }
```

Write:

```
string currentUser = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName;
                SPSite spSite = SPContext.Current.Site;
                SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
                {
                    System.Web.HttpContext currentContext = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
                    System.Web.HttpContext.Current = null;
                    try
                    {
                        // Set the context of the site to the SPSite site
                        SPServiceContext context = SPServiceContext.GetContext(spSite);
                        //Create and instance of the UserProfileManager
                        UserProfileManager profileManager = new UserProfileManager(context);
                        UserProfile userProfile = profileManager.GetUserProfile(currentUser);
                        userProfile["customPropertyName"].Value = "True";
                        userProfile.Commit();
                    }                   

                    finally
                    {
                        System.Web.HttpContext.Current = currentContext;
                    }
                });
```

Do I have to use for read also the below code as used in case of write?

before try

```
 System.Web.HttpContext currentContext = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
                            System.Web.HttpContext.Current = null;
```

in finally:

```
 System.Web.HttpContext.Current = currentContext;
```

Why is it that we have to do like this for the write?

Answer (score 2):

You should not have to get the current user. Calling GetUserProfile(bool) will get the user profile of the current user, and optionally create the user profile if it does not exist. The user should have permission to update their own profile, so it is very bad practice to use RunWithElevatedPriveledges. You should only need the Service Context for the request, not sure why you need any of the other code.

You have to decide what is best for your case. It is possible that a user will hit your page without a Profile, if that happens you have to determine what to do in code. Create a profile or handle the error and indicate that they need a profile to use the page. This is not something set in stone. You have to decide based on your business and how you manage Profiles in your farm.

RunWithElevatedPrivileges = RWEP as a shorthand. Again, this is only to be used as a last resort, and should be avoided then too. If you set up the properties on the User Profile correctly, this should be unnecessary.

Comment: can you provide a reference to support that profileManager.GetUserProfile() without a parameter will get the user profile of the current user

Comment: I am not clear on why you need that at all. The code inside your try block with the site reference should be enough. As long as the properties in the IPA are configured so that the user can update them.

Comment: My reference for writing value to user profile property: http://tejinderrai.org/2011/07/25/sharepoint-2010-writing-user-profile-properties-programatically/

Comment: Also, if we dont set: System.Web.HttpContext.Current = null; before the TRY block, then, we get error on COMMIT.

Comment: Sorry, should have been the GetUserProfile(bool) version. Then you decide if you want to trip a profile create.

Comment: You want me to set it to 'false'? I dont want to create any thing I just need to read the info and set the info for an existing user profile. Also you have not yet answered about the setting context to null..

Comment: Try it without the RWEP. If the permissions are set correctly on the User Profile you should not need it. You question was about Best Practice. RWEP is far from "best".

Comment: can you point me to what is RWEP. I have not come across this, please. sorry you mean I am using RWEP? I didnot get your point.